# Bash Shell mean function not printing

Tags: bash, shell

I have to take the mean of a matrix file. I am currently using temp files to do this. I have what seems to be code that should work, i am just having trouble printing it out/getting it to work correctly. I have been at it for a few hours but can't seem to get it right. Do you guys see anything wrong? Also im sorry is just a function I call that throws an error This code is also bash shell

Here is my code:

```
mean)

if [ $# -gt 2 ]
then
  imsorry

elif [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
iterator=0
NUM_COUNT=0
NUM_SUM=0
mytempColumn="tempcolfile"
mytempRow="temprowfile"
mytempMean="tempmeanfile"

NUM_OF_COLS=$( head -n 1 $lineread | wc -w)

  while [[ ! $iterator -ge $NUM_OF_COLS ]]
    do

      cut -f $iterator $lineread > $mytempColumn
      while read lineread1
      do
        NUM_SUM='expr $NUM_SUM + $lineread1'
        NUM_COUNT='expr $NUM_COUNT + 1'
done <$mytempColumn

#mean equation that was given to us by the instructor


meanequation=$(((NUM_SUM + (NUM_COUNT/2)*( (NUM_SUM>0)*2-1)) / NUM_COUNT))

echo "$meanequation" > $"mytempMean"
cat $mytempMean | tr "\n" "\t" > "$mytempRow"

if [[ $iterator -eq $NUM_OF_COLS ]]
then
  rev "$temprowfile" > "temp123"
  cat "temp123" | cut -c 2- >"temp321"
  rev "temp321">$mytempRow
fi



cat $mytempRow
iterator=$((iterator+1))
done
rm -f tempmeanfile

echo $mytempMean


fi

;;
```

Comment: `head -n 1 $lineread` makes no sense.  At this point `$lineread` is the empty string, so this will be an error.  If you have previous code that sets `$lineread`, you should include it.  But `head` is expecting a file name, and I hope you are not putting a filename in a variable named `$lineread`.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation: proper indentation often easily reveals the bug.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the input file, as well as what you expect from the output?  I think there should be a much simpler solution to your problem.